# I'm trying to parse some log file with Python regex but get the following error: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, regex, syntax-error

I'm trying to parse some log file with Python regex but get the following error:
"unexpected character after line continuation character"

```
import re
fh=':-U campus -u stevendu -l h_data=4G,h_rt=86400,h_vmem=4G -pe single 1:'
m = re.search(('h_data=') (\d+) ([G,M]), fh)
print(m.group(0))
print(m.group(1))
print(m.group(2))

I suppose to get:
h_data=4G
4
G
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Your regex pattern isn't actually inside a string...

Comment: Use `re.search(r'h_data=(\d+)([GM])', fh)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following regular expression to match your groups:

```
import re

text = ':-U campus -u stevendu -l h_data=4G,h_rt=86400,h_vmem=4G -pe single 1:'

match = re.search('(h_data=(\d{1})([G|M]))', text)

print(match.groups())  # ('h_data=4G', '4', 'G')
print(match.group(1))  # h_data=4G
print(match.group(2))  # 4
print(match.group(3))  # G
```

Comment: Thank you, Darius! Your advice was very useful!